# @Async is not working in REST class

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, annotations

I am working on a WebService project built using Spring. All the configuration are done using Annotation. There is one method which sends the push notification. As there are many notifications to send, which causes delay in response. So, I apply @Async annotation to my "sendPushnotification" method. But, still no improvement in response. I have gone through some of the blogs and stackoverflow to find the solution. But, no success. I have applied following annotation to my Service class.

```
@Component
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableAsync
```

Method from which async called.

```
@POST
@Path("/sampleService")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response sampleService(@FormParam ...) {
    ...
    List<User> commentors = <other method to fetch commentors>;
    sendPushnotification(commentors);
    ...
}
```

My async method.

```
@Async
private void sendPushnotification(List<User> commentors) {
    if (commentors != null) {
        for (User user : commentors) {
            try {
                int numNewComments = ps.getCommentsUnseenByUser(user); 

                sendMessage("ios", user, "2", "" + numNewComments, "true"); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Have you registered an executor with an appropriate number of threads?

Comment: Have you properly integrated Jersey (or whatever JAX RS implementation you are using) with Spring?

Comment: Yes. It is properly configured. The app is working perfectly fine. All requests and responses are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking the method on `this`

```
sendPushnotification(commentors);
// equivalent to
this.sendPushnotification(commentors);
```

That won't work. Spring works by proxying your beans to provide functionality. It gives you back a proxy bean which has a reference to the real object. So the caller sees and invokes

```
proxy.someEnhancedMethod()
```

But what happens is

```
proxy.someEnhancedMethod() -> some enhanced logic -> target.someEnhancedMethod()
```

But in your `sampleService` service method, you don't have a reference to the proxy, you have a reference to the target. You've gained nothing, basically. I suggest moving the `@Async` logic to a different type, declaring and injecting a bean of that type into your resource.

Spring explains all of the above in the documentation, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying).

Comment: I am reviewing the link.